# symfony2 Forms with 2 distinct objects

Tags: forms, symfony, entities

I would like to do a form with two distincts objets that are not related to one another.

Is it possible?
Do I have to do 2 forms on the same page and a with javascript sumit them all together when the user click on a Javascript Submit Button? Or is possible to manage it just with one form with Symfony. If yes any tips about how to proceed it?

Comment: try embedding second form into the first one http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#embedded-forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this solutions is best one, but it's working on one of my project, where I had similar problem.

You need to create FormType for each of Entity and correctly define `data_class` in `setDefaultOptions` method. In our example these are EventType and UserType.

For this to work, you need create class which represent both of entities. I call then Form Models.

```
// Acme\DemoBundle\Form\Model\Custom.php

class Custom
{
    public $event;
    public $user;
}
```

And now just create last FormType which glue this entities together in one form.

```
// Acme\DemoBundle\Form\CustomType.php

class CustomType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('Event', new EventType());
        $builder->add('User', new UserType());
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\DemoBundle\Form\Model\Custom'
        ));
    }

    ...
}
```